# UILabel with given transparency but textLabel should be opaque

Tags: iphone, ios, transparency, uilabel

I have a UILabel which should have transparency (alpha) = .6 but Text of UILable should have alpha = 1. is this possible? thanks for any suggestion in advance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
label.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.6];
label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1];
```